# Can an Indian GSM phone be used in the USA?

Tags: sim-card, gsm, import

I'm considering buying the Oppo F9 Pro, which has a dual sim GSM slot. I currently have consumer cellular service with a nano GSM sim card. would I be able to import the Indian phone and use it here without any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search brings up this site:

https://www.frequencycheck.com/compatibility/XnDDU6Y/oppo-f9-dual-sim-td-lte-vn-ph-64gb-cph1823-f9-pro/united-states

Which indicates that the Oppo F9 Pro would only have **2/2.5G speeds** on **some** US carriers with GSM and **NO** support on the rest of the carriers for signal or speed. It would appear to be limited pre-2008 data speeds in the United States and presumably still usable as a phone/SMS on supported carriers.

Answer (score 0):

As a more general answer:

1. Look up what **frequency bands** are used by your **carrier**.
2. Do the same for your specific phone **model**.

There are websites dedicated to answering this exact question, for example [frequencycheck.com](https://www.frequencycheck.com/).

From this site (or a Google search), we can figure out that **Oppo F9 Pro** supports:

- 900 (E-GSM)   GSM
- 1800 (DCS)    GSM
- 1900 (PCS)    GSM

Now you'll have to compare this with whatever info your find for the carrier you wish to use, the website mentioned above makes the comparison a lot easier. Here's a hardcoded link for your device with "country" set to the US:

https://www.frequencycheck.com/compatibility/XnDDU6Y/oppo-f9-dual-sim-td-lte-vn-ph-64gb-cph1823-f9-pro/united-states

In short, you'll only get support for 1900 (PCS) on **some** carriers (GRPS/EDGE). No speeds to write home about.